# What is the latest Serilog version compatible w/ vb.Net 2.0 (yeah, I know...) if any?

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, serilog

Our outfit has been standardizing on Serilog logging, and I would like to utilize it, if practical, with a new app I'm building on the vb.Net 2.0 target framework (long story...).

I'll go with .TXT logging if I have to, but thought Serilog logging would be an improvement.

No code yet - early-on design decision.  Tanx, in advance!

Comment: The oldest stable version of Serilog in NuGet - 1.0.1 - only targets .NET 4.5. I doubt that you'll be able to find a build that runs on 2.0, for which Microsoft support ended 8 years ago...

Comment: dont do this to yourself - either kill the code and don't maintain it or get to .net 4.6.1 or net472

Comment: Also worth considering that NLog has full structured logging support in NLog versions >= 4.5 but will likely have similar restrictions

Comment: Jon, tanx!  For the heckuvit I tried Serilog 1.0.1 from NuGet and it errored.

Comment: Ruben, tanx!  Here's the long story:  Wksta supporting sophisticated measurement tool runs Win2k.  New sophisticated measurement tool = $1/2 M;  New sftwe for sophisticated measurement tool = $125k ==> not happening, I use .NET 2.0